# use of dynamic casting , when class object returned

Tags: java, spring

I am new to java while learning dynamic casting I got a doubt like this, for example, I have 2 classes, class a and class b or more, i can cast the class using instanceof to get my desired method fom object and got the output by using multiple if else if statements and casting can be done easily

however the lines of code is too many.

App,Eep, Shop are my classes, I have put void as return type because im not sure what to give as return typs since the class varies.

```
private void  getInstance(App dd) {
if (dd instanceof Eep) {
        Eep coi = (Eep) dd;
    }
else{
Shop coi = (Shop) dd;
}
}
```

what i want to know is will it be possible to return the casted class object which varies depending on condition, i am not able to find the answer. I think we can return using Object but casting it again will be required I think, could anyone help me with this.

Comment: If you find yourself casting, it usually means you're doing something wrong.  There are various ways to avoid needing to cast, but it's not clear from the question which would be most appropriate here.  Chances are good, however, that the assignment anticipates that you will use one or more techniques that you have been learning about in class.

Comment: It is a little strange why your "getInstance" method returns "void"?

Comment: @Stone I put void in because I was not sure what needs return type needs to be used. since depending on condition the class name will vary. yeah it would be possible in that scenario

Comment: Is it possible to let the caller decide  Eep or Shop should be used?  If yes, Java has a concept of "overload" and you could change it into two methods. For the return object type, you could design one common parent class or interface if you need.
`private Eep  getInstance(Eep dd) ` and `private Shop  getInstance(Shop dd) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Java you can use [JEP 394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394), Pattern Matching for instanceof:

```
private void  getInstance(App dd) {
if (dd instanceof Eep e) {
  e.myMethodFromEep();
}
if (dd instanceof Shop s) {
  s.myMethodFromShop();
}
```

This eliminates the need for casting. It's still verbose with all those `if`. Furthermore, it smells of bad design if you have a method that does different things depending on the actual type of a parameter via `instanceof`. Maybe you need polymorphism instead?